# upgrading to spring 5.0.7.RELEASE is causing issues with parseStringValue

Tags: java, spring

We have a Java program and a 3rd party API that stay in sync with Spring between the two.
After upgrading from 4.2.5.RELEASE to 5.0.7.RELEASE
 I'm seeing the following error in one of the files:

> The method parseStringValue(String, Properties, HashSet) is
>   undefined for the type
>   NestedPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer   NestedPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java

I attempted to use this import instead PropertyPlaceholderHelper but then I seemed to be going down a rabbit hole of errors and I wasn't even sure that was the right approach.

This is the page of code in it's entirety (minus some redacted info):

```
            package redacted.primavera.common.spring;

            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.HashSet;
            import java.util.List;
            import java.util.Properties;

            import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
            import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
            import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
            import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
            import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
            import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;


            /**
             * Extends the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to implement nested resource
             * location placeholders.  Properties from the top-level resources may be
             * used to define nested resources.
             *   
             * @author redacted
             *
             */
            public class NestedPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer implements ApplicationContextAware {
                private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
                private Resource[] topLocations;
                private List<String> nestedLocations;


                /*
                 * Post-process the bean factory.  Add the nested resource locations to the
                 * top-level resource locations before processing.
                 *  
                 * (non-Javadoc)
                 * @see org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer#postProcessBeanFactory(org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory)
                 */
                @Override
                public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
                    try {
                        Properties props = mergeProperties();

                        List<Resource> merged = new ArrayList<Resource>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < topLocations.length; i++) {
                            merged.add(topLocations[i]);
                        }

                        for (String nestedLocation : this.nestedLocations) {
                            String location = parseStringValue(nestedLocation.replaceAll("#\\{", "\\${"), props, new HashSet<String>());
                            if (location != null) {
                                Resource[] resources = this.applicationContext.getResources(location);
                                for (int i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
                                    Resource resource = resources[i];
                                    if (!merged.contains(resource)) {
                                        merged.add(resource);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        setLocations(merged.toArray(new Resource[merged.size()]));
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("", e);
                    }

                    super.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
                }

                /*
                 * (non-Javadoc)
                 * @see org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware#setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext)
                 */
                public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
                    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
                }

                /*
                 * Set resource locations and save a local copy.
                 * 
                 * (non-Javadoc)
                 * @see org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport#setLocations(org.springframework.core.io.Resource[])
                 */
                @Override
                public void setLocations(Resource[] locations) {
                    this.topLocations = new Resource[locations.length];
                    System.arraycopy(locations, 0, this.topLocations, 0, locations.length);

                    super.setLocations(locations);
                }

                /**
                 * Set the nested resource locations.
                 * @param nestedLocations
                 */
                public void setNestedLocations(List<String> nestedLocations) {
                    this.nestedLocations = nestedLocations;
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parseStringValue(String strVal, Properties props, Set visitedPlaceholders)
```

was deprecated.

As Jens suggested here is my refactored code changes to fix the compile issues:

1. Added an import:

   `import` `org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper;`
2. Method variable:

   `PropertyPlaceholderHelper pph = new` `PropertyPlaceholderHelper(DEFAULT_PLACEHOLDER_PREFIX, DEFAULT_PLACEHOLDER_SUFFIX);`

3. Replaced method call:

```
String location = pph.replacePlaceholders(nestedLocation.replaceAll("#\\{", "\\${"), props);
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the [javadoc of version 4.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) this method was deprecated and removed in version 5.x.

> parseStringValue(String strVal, Properties props, Set visitedPlaceholders)
>
> Deprecated.
>
> as of Spring 3.0, in favor of using resolvePlaceholder(java.lang.String, java.util.Properties, int) with PropertyPlaceholderHelper. Only retained for compatibility with Spring 2.5 extensions.

So you have to refactor you code and use [PropertyPlaceholderHelper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/PropertyPlaceholderHelper.html)